# Autorun .bat-file to check if computer is unplugged. If so, kill processes

Tags: windows, batch, script

At startup, I want a script to check if the computer is unplugged (i.e. running on battery). If so, I want to kill a few processes.

After scouring superuser and stackoverflow, I've come this far:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get   BatteryStatus') DO SET BatteryStatus=%%A
IF "%BatteryStatus%"=="1" (
taskkill /im DMT.exe
taskkill /im AudioSwitcher.exe
)
```

With ECHO ON I get:

```
>SET BatteryStatus=2
>SET BatteryStatus=
>IF "" == "1"
```

Why doesn't it save the number 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why doesn't it save the number 2?

If you run the following command in a `cmd` shell:

```
WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus
```

The output will typically be:

```
F:\test>WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus
BatteryStatus
2


F:\test>
```

As the above out shows, `wmic` outputs an additional blank line.

For a blank lines `%%A` will be an empty string and `BatteryStatus` will be undefined.

The easiest fix is to pipe `|` the output of `wmic` to `findstr /r /v "^$"` which will strip any blank lines.

**Corrected batch file (test.cmd):**

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') DO SET BatteryStatus=%%A
IF "%BatteryStatus%"=="1" (
taskkill /im DMT.exe
taskkill /im AudioSwitcher.exe
)
```

**Output with `echo` enabled:**

```
F:\test>test

F:\test>rem @ECHO OFF

F:\test>FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %A in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus | findstr /r /v "^$"') DO SET BatteryStatus=%A

F:\test>SET BatteryStatus=2

F:\test>IF "2" == "1" (
taskkill /im DMT.exe
 taskkill /im AudioSwitcher.exe
)
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.